# Hex Editor - Seems that Peplink .report files have changed again, can they still be opened?

Tags: hex, xor, diagnostics, hex-editors

I am trying to examine Peplink *.report files to diagnose a router that is no longer under support. I attempted following this previous thread as well as the thread linked in that thread: [Hex Editor - Peplink .diag files changed - Can they still be opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115679/hex-editor-peplink-diag-files-changed-can-they-still-be-opened)

However, I have attempted both of the methods, as well as other ways of trimming the hex file, but without success.

These files start with `DR000001` and contain some sort of header. There is no starting `Pe1337__` and there is instead a `Salted__` which occurs later in the file.

I can provide a sample of the new *.report file if needed.

Any help would be appreciated.